# How to Keep record id in visualforce?

Tags: jquery-ui, salesforce, visualforce, apex

I just tackle with one scenario in which i want to maintain a particular record id information throughout the different tab in salesforce org.In this when i select a particular record in jqgrid using radio button all the information related to that record must be fetch in other visualforce tab.The table have different relationship with other table.